# jQuery not available in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below are my HTML, css, and JavaScript. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Note: I create the JavaScript in a separate file, not in the same files as HTML.

Do I have to add any additional link or code on the jQuery file to make it execute the function?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<title>CodePlay</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseenter(function(){
        $("div").fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
    $("div").mouseleave(function(){
        $("div").fadeTo("fast", 0.25);
    });
});
```

Comment: are the files in the same directory?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe yes they are, the css file is working but not the jquery

Comment: I'm not seeing the script to include jQuery. If you open the package manager and type 'jQuery' then it should let you import that script tag for use, as long as it's above your script.js.

Comment: lol, just noticed you haven't added the reference to jQuery in you file. Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` before your script

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe this will go inside the jQuery file right?

Comment: Nope. In the HTML file, before the reference to your script. Your script *depends* on jQuery to work

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Thanks a million for that. Been stuck on it since yesterday :-))). Create an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the script for jQuery in your head part of the html code, add this line in:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

That line is for HTML5, which you are using, so you are ok. If you are using HTML 4 or XHTML, you will need to refer to it as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Good luck with the coding.